# Time gt query not working with mongoid and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I am using mongoid and ruby on rails.

I am storing `created_at` time with mongoid using

```
include Mongoid::Timestamps
```

So let's say I have 3 post created like this

```
{"post":"1","created_at": "2014-03-25 13:04:43"}
{"post":"2","created_at": "2014-03-25 13:04:44"}
{"post":"3","created_at": "2014-03-25 13:04:45"}
```

Now I want to get all posts which is created after `{"post":"2"}`, that is after `"2014-03-25 13:04:44"`, so that should only return `{"post":"3"}`

```
Model.where(:created_at.gt => "2014-03-25 13:04:44")
```

But with above query it is returning `{"post":"2"}` and `{"post":"3"}`, so `{"post":"2"}`, should not be there.

Also `.lt` queries work as expected.

Any Idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

the problem is in time zone... the mongoid `created_at` field is stored in `UTC` time zone

you can use the following which will work

```
Model.where(:created_at.gt => post_2_instance.created_at)
```

given that `post_2_instance` is `{"post":"2","created_at": "2014-03-25 13:04:44"}`

but if you want to query using date you can use the following

```
Model.where(:created_at.gt => DateTime.parse("2014-03-25 13:04:43").in_time_zone('UTC'))
```

the weird behaviour is reported to [this JIRA issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-3590)

Comment: what is the output of `Post.last.created_at.time_zone` ?

Comment: the weird thing is that the first solution stopped working for me... while testing now :S

Comment: the thing is I am fetching feed based on the time string sent by client. Now client sent "2014-03-25 13:04:44", which is working for .lt but not for .gt

Comment: i made sure to test that before posting it... then the same code i copied from the rails console is now not working.. :/

Comment: No I have not found anything. I used 2nd solution.

Comment: I've edited the answer to a working solution that worked for me... check it and tell me